# Question with Glassfish 4 - SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1

I have a problem, a certificate was recently generated for a Glassfish 4 server, currently the certificate is already imported into the Keystore.

But when I write the alias in the listener, the page stops loading, if I go back to the previous certificate which is s1as, it is normal.

Can you help me with any clue?

I have used the following commands to import the certificate to JKS, the repositories key is by default (changeit)

```
./keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias sierraexportadora2024 -file /home/uti/2062319390.crt -keystore /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
./keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file /home/uti/USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt -keystore /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
./keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermed -file /home/uti/SectigoRSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crt -keystore /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
./keytool -import -alias sierraexportadora.gob.pe -keystore /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file /home/uti/2062319390.crt
```